# Amplify Auth events don't work in android

Tags: java, android, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm working in on an app that uses authentication from the AWS Amplify library.
I tried to check the sign-in state by looking at Amplify's auth events, but it
doesn't work. I tried to verify with logcat, but it only shows me the output of
the fetch.

```java
Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
    result -> Log.i("AmplifyQuickstart", result.toString()),
    error -> Log.e("AmplifyQuickstart", error.toString())
);

Amplify.Hub.subscribe(HubChannel.AUTH, hubEvent -> {
    if (hubEvent.getName().equals(InitializationStatus.SUCCEEDED.toString())) {
        Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Auth successfully initialized");
    } else if (hubEvent.getName().equals(InitializationStatus.FAILED.toString())) {
        Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Auth failed to succeed");
    } else {
        switch (AuthChannelEventName.valueOf(hubEvent.getName())) {
            case SIGNED_IN:
                Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Auth just became signed in.");
                break;
            case SIGNED_OUT:
                Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Auth just became signed out.");
                break;
            case SESSION_EXPIRED:
                Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Auth session just expired.");
                break;
            default:
                Log.w("AuthQuickstart", "Unhandled Auth Event: " + AuthChannelEventName.valueOf(hubEvent.getName()));
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There is some work being done to simplify the error handling in auth. Refer to: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/pull/757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I succeed to handle the problem is to pass the error lambda
reference to `errorAuthenticationHandle` function as follows:

```java
Amplify.Auth.signIn(this.userName, password,
    result -> Log.i("AuthQuickstart", result.isSignInComplete() ?
        "Sign in succeeded" : "Sign in not complete"),
    this::errorAuthenticationHandle
);

private void errorAuthenticationHandle(AuthException error) {
    Log.e("AmplifyQuickstart", error.toString());

    switch (getErrorNumber(error)) {
        // Server require password reset
        case RESET:
            // Some code
            break;

        case FAILED:
            // Some code
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The getErrorNumber is simple regex function that export the error code number

Comment: But it's not the most stable solution for amplify updates